# I want to verify the JWT token

Tags: jwt, fastapi

I want to verify the JWT token using the verify_token function from the POST request. But it is not verifying the token though the GET method is creating it successfully. Here is the code. I used FASTAPI to create the API. Do I have to store the token in the local storage? I don't want users to login to the website, they will convert the pdf just by uploading it. All I want is that the JWT token will be in the header of the upload request and the verify_token function will verify it and upon verifying it will convert the pdf to docx. In the local swagger server, I can generate the token from the GET request but the  Post request is not verifying it.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI,Depends,HTTPException,Request
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer, HTTPAuthorizationCredentials
from fastapi import File, UploadFile
#from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from pdf2docx import Converter
import uvicorn
#import os
import uuid
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from jose import jwt

app = FastAPI()
security = HTTPBearer()
file_name=""
SECRET_KEY = "Adnan123"
ALGORITHM = "HS256"

def generate_token() -> str:
    issued_at = datetime.utcnow()
    not_before = issued_at + timedelta(minutes=1)  # Token is not valid before 1 minute from issuance

    payload = {
        "authorized": True,
        "jti": str(uuid.uuid4()),  # Generate a unique ID for each token
        "iat": issued_at,
        "nbf": not_before
    }
    token = jwt.encode(payload, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return token

def verify_token(token: str) -> dict:

    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        return payload
    except :
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid or expired token")

@app.post("/upload")
async def upload_pdf(file: UploadFile = File(...),auth: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Depends(security)):
    try:
        verify_token(auth.credentials)
    except HTTPException as e:
        return e.detail

    global file_name
    name = file.filename
    file_name = name[:-4] + ".docx"
    alpha = file.content_type
    print(alpha)
    if alpha == 'application/pdf':
        filename = "./upload/" + name
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(contents)
            docx_file = filename[:-4] + ".docx"
            cv = Converter(filename)
            cv.convert(docx_file)
            cv.close()
    else:
        return {"message": "Error uploading the file"}
    file.file.close()




@app.get("/token")
async def get_token(request: Request):
    token = generate_token()
    return {"token": token}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('main:app',
                host='127.0.0.1',
                port=8000,
                reload=True)
```

I want to verify the token from the /upload route and then convert the pdf that will be uploaded

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate the Token
2. Save it in Local Storage
3. When sending a post request, add it in the header.

Try it from postman/swagger or any api testing platform, steps below :

1. Generate the token.
2. Copy the token.
3. When sending a post request,add it in the headers along with your payload.

Screen Shot below from Postman:

[image: Adding Authorization]
[image: Headers Section in Postman]